Avoid PBI loading screen after applying filters with PBI Embedded JS
I set Basic filters using
await report.setFilters(pbiFilters)
Then, I render my reports using this function
await report.render()
which results in this loading screen
Power Bi Embedded Loading screen
But let's say I want to add new filters to the already rendered page? In my experience, this causes the loading screen above to trigger again (because I have to rerender the report when new filters are applied).
If I use a slicer within the Iframe and choose a filter from there, the loading screen is not triggered.
How can i set filters, using powerbi-embedded and PowerBI-javascript, while not causing the iframe to trigger the loading screen?
I have tried filtering on visuals, pages and reports. I have also tried the updateFilters function for each. However, the outcome is the same. I have not tried to filter the slicers in the embedded report directly. But this is not something I want to do, as there may be many different slicers that may change, which makes it difficult to maintain.

A useEffect caused the embedconfig to reset the entire embedding - causing the loading screen to appear.
Key takeaway: setFilters or updateFilters do not cause the loading screen to appear. If the loading screen appears, you have done it wrong.
